# Plotting graph using QtOctave for C++/ROS-generated data

Tags: ros, c++, graph

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I would like to use QtOctave in order to do the following:

1. To plot a graph in which the values are published by a topic from another node.
2. To plot a graph for any published messages or variables.

Anyway, my written code is in C++. Is there any way that we can realize this using QtOctave and C++ running ROS? Hopefully, somebody who is familiar with this tool can guide me on this..

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12274/plotting-graph-using-qtoctave-for-c++/ros-generated-data/) by [alfa_80](https://answers.ros.org/users/121/alfa_80/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1053 on 2011-12-08

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Have you tried [rxplot](http://www.ros.org/wiki/rxplot)?

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2011-12-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [alfa_80](https://answers.ros.org/users/121/alfa_80/) on 2011-12-13**:
@tfoote: Thanks for the clarification.

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2011-12-10**:
It's relatively easy to publish what you want to plot to view it in rxplot.  And from your description everything is published.  In general dependencies like qtOctave are bad to bring into tools and libraries for they are usually heavy dependencies and not related to core functionality.

**Comment by [alfa_80](https://answers.ros.org/users/121/alfa_80/) on 2011-12-08**:
With this rxplot, every variable has to be associated with topic, right? what if the variable that we want to plot  is not associated with any topic, is there any way to plot it?